# Camel route depending on header. Namespace breaks condition

Tags: xml, soap, apache-camel

I'm following the "Message Router" pattern explained in https://camel.apache.org/message-router.html

However, I'm having problems with conditions on headers with namespaces.

The XML message I'm receiving is like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <DF xmlns="http://mycompany/smth">myElement</DF>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:processIncomingMessage xmlns:ns2="http://a.namespace.com/">
      <arg0>something</arg0>
    </ns2:processIncomingMessage>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And this is my route:

```
from("switchyard://CamelInterfaceService") 
    .log("Header: ${headers}") 
    .log("Received message for 'CamelInterfaceService' : ${body}") 
    .choice() 
        .when(header("DF").isEqualTo("myElement")) 
        .to("switchyard://OtherService") 
        .log("SENT.........") 
        .end();
```

However, `OtherService` is not called.

If I change:

```
<DF xmlns="http://mycompany/smth">myElement</DF>
```

to:

```
<DF>myElement</DF>
```

it works...but it is something I cannot really change...so, how can I modify my camel route to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: You can just check the message header to see what does switchyard put the message header of DF with the namespace?

Comment: Dont know if this might help I had some problems with name spaces a while ago see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765255/apache-camel-java-and-xpath

Comment: @WillemJiang This is what appears in the Message Context:
{http://mycompany/smth}DF ...........: myElement

Comment: @Namphibian Thank you, but the thing is that the XML I received does't contain a namespace prefix for the "DF" element...

Comment: It looks like a bug of switchyard, you may need to ask help from switchyard.